# Why is the peak efficiency higher in Buck-Boost Controller when running below the AM band and lower above AM band?

Tags: power-electronics, frequency, emc, efficiency, buck-boost

I have seen this part LT8253/LT8253A, and it says in the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt8253-8253a.pdf) that "The LT8253 can deliver up to 100W output power with 98% peak efficiency when running below the AM band.
The LT8253A can deliver up to 60W output power with 95% peak efficiency when running above the AM band."

I came across other buck-boost topologies as well and they follow the same pattern.

Another question. I'm sorry if I sound dumb but what does (400 kHz) mean in this sample design? Why can't we have a standard in this regard?

[image: Automotive 60W USB-C Power Delivery Charger (400kHz)]

Comment: Please link the datasheet so that each viewer does not have to seach it out for him/herself. Thank-you.

Comment: 400 KHz is presumably the frequency the converter is running at in that example (although you can probably check in the datasheet to be sure). Are you familiar with what a buck or boost converter does?

Comment: Further on in the datasheet it talks about the extra energy involved in driving the mosfets at 2MHz. The AM band is referenced as you generally want to avoid working around those frequencies as you could cause interference. More so in an automotive application as an AM radio is expected in that environment. So you either have your switching frequency above or below.

Comment: The AM band goes from ~530 kHz to 1600 kHz. As the power of this converter is fairly high, it must be functioning out of this band for EMI reasons. So 400 kHz is well out of these frequencies and also the other model which runs at 2000 kHz. Moreover, it can use 'spread spectrum" to minimize "noise" generated, and slew rate voltage can be controlled, thus for low-EMI. For the "standards", see the laws. These are very well defined in EU countries ... french "CISPR" and "others" ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_EMC_test_standards

Comment: It is also "logical" that the efficiency decreases with higher frequency (losses are generally higher), although it is not really "obvious" ...

Comment: Note that switching losses are proportional to switching frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Switching losses increase in proportion to frequency .Conduction losses stay the same .Expect the efficiency of a hard switched convertor to fall markedly with frequency .When you run at 400KHz you could get interference at 800KHz amd 1200KHz and 1600KHz